# Incrementing date in yyyymmddhhmmss.mmm format in Java

Tags: java, date

I want to increment the milliseconds in any given date in the format yyyymmddhhmmss.mmm in each iteration. mmm here represents milliseconds. And I want to perfom this operation in Java 1.5.

For example: 20120823151034.567 should be incremented to 20120823151034.568

Answer (score 4):

You can use `long` milli-seconds which make incrementing trivial.

```
final String input = "20120823151034.567";
final DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss.SSS");

Date d = df.parse(input);
d.setTime(d.getTime()+1);
System.out.println(df.format(d));
```

I wouldn't use Calendar as its very slow.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Thanks a million.

Comment: You'll still need Calendar if you want to control the TimeZone explicitly. Otherwise this is the better choice for this particular case.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Assuming your input and output timezones are the same, this shouldn't be such a problem. You could have a problem when daylight saving changes as time could appear to go backwards.

Comment: DST effects will be the same whether you use a `Date` or a `Calendar`. In fact, they'll have exactly the same behaviour when the locale's default timezone is used.

Comment: Oh yes, keep in mind that if you reuse the `Calender` instance, there is no performance penalty. It's construction that takes time. Not that I would recommend messing around with shared thread-unsafe `Calendar`s, though.

Answer (score 3):

You can parse `String` to `Date` object and use `getTime()` and `setTime(long l)` to modify date. Then you can convert `Date` object back to `String`. For parsing `String` and converting `Date` object back to `String` you can use `SimpleDateFormat` class.

Answer (score 3):

The best class to use for this operation is [`Calendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html). You set it to the desired date, and then use

```
myCalendar.add(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 1);
```

to advance it by one millisecond. Use [`DateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html) to produce string representations.

Answer (score 1):

This gives you what you want. It will work across any day/month/year boundary, as well as handling the start and end of daylight saving time.

```
  final String input = "20120823151034.567";
  final DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss.SSS");
  final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
  c.setTime(df.parse(input));
  c.add(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 1);
  System.out.println(df.format(c.getTime()));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Calendar Class as well as Date Class for this....

**Date Class:**

```
final String dateStr = "20120823151034.567";
final DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss.SSS");

Date date = format.parse(input);
date.setTime(date.getTime()+1);
System.out.println(format.format(date));
```

**Calendar Class:**

```
final String dateStr = "20120823151034.567";
final DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss.SSS");

Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTime(format.parse(dateStr ));
c.add(Calendar.MILLISECOND,1);
System.out.println(format.format(c.getTime()));
```

In both cases, format.parse() has the potential to throw a ParseException, which you will need to catch and handle.

Comment: +1 for having both methods. It does hammer home that Calendar is overkill for this job, though.

Comment: @slim Not quite, since the API calls for the Calendar case are about the same, if not cleaner. The second example just contains duplicated code, as well as exception handling that would be due in both cases just the same.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik ... and the parseException occurs in both. I am going to edit this to reflect that.

Comment: This is so beautiful, now all the answers share the first two lines! And it is my personal style to use `final` local vars, almost nobody else writes it like that.

Comment: @Marko Thanks for praising the style

Answer (score 0):

An alternative without using Calendar (although, Calendar is fine)

```
 final String input = "20120814120000.111";
 final DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss.SSS");

 Date date = new format.parse(input);
 long time = date.getTime();

 Date incrementedDate = new Date(time + 1);
 System.out.println(format.format(date));
```

Comment: You obviously copy-pasted my code. That's my birthday you're using as an example.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Busted :) - Your dateformat was ideal, so I nabbed that and the previous line.